# Flutter Web App TextFormField don't work on Chrome iOS

Tags: flutter, web, textfield

The web TextFormFields doesn't work on Chrome iOS how can I fix this issue? Any ideas, please guide me!

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u find any workaround ? I'm facing this issue on flutter 3.7.1 lol

Comment: Hi @MarcelloCâmara I just build it like:
`flutter build web --web-renderer html --release`
Happy coding ;)